# jQuery fade out & fade in wont redirect me

Tags: jquery, transition, fadein, fadeout

I am using this jquery script to fade out and fade in pages,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").css("display", "none");
    $("body").fadeIn(1000);

    $("li").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);
    });

    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }
});
</script>
```

fade out part works well, however, fadeIn, doesnt. To be exact, page fades out, then there is a transition to second page, but it wont redirect me to link location but to "undefined".

Navigation is in php which produce

```
<ul> list with <li>.
```

Any advices? :)

Answer (score 0):

`linkLocation` is defined only within the `$(document).ready()` anonymous function, so your `redirectPage()` function doesn't know what the value of `linkLocation` is. You have to use it like so:

```
$("body").fadeOut(1000, function() {
  window.location = linkLocation;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your `li` element actually have a href attribute?

are you sure the href attribute does not belong to a `<a>` element, and that you are referencing the wrong element with `this`?

```
<li id="mylist" href="http://google.com"></li>
```

Looks strange to me?

Comment: @PeterAbsolon - If the answer is correct you should probably accept it?